# The equivalent conditions for closure in a normed space.

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \| \cdot \| )$ be a normed space.

---

**Definition (Closure)**

Define $\overline A$ as the smallest closed set containing $A$.

Then, call $\overline A$ closure of $A$.

---

I want to prove
\begin{align}
\overline A&=\{ x \in X \mid \forall \epsilon >0, \exists a\in A\ ;\ \| x-a \| < \epsilon \} \\
&=\{ x\in X \mid \exists \{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \subset A\ ;\ x_n \to x \ \mathrm{in} \ X \}.
\end{align}

---

Let $$B :=\{ x \in X \mid \forall \epsilon >0, \exists a\in A\ ;\ \| x-a \| < \epsilon \},$$$$\ C:=\{ x\in X \mid \exists \{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty \subset A\ ;\ x_n \to x \ \mathrm{in} \ X \}$$

I have to prove $\overline A=B=C.$

So far, I proved $\overline A \subset B=C$ so all that is left is $B\subset \overline A$ or $C\subset \overline A$

I have difficulty in showing $x \in B \Rightarrow x \in \overline A$ or $x \in C \Rightarrow x \in \overline A$.

$\overline A$  is defined as the smallest closed set containing $A$. Letting $x\in B$ (or $C$), what should I say in order to show $x\in \overline A$ ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which definition of "closed" are you using?

Comment: I checked the definition of open and closed and I was able to prove  $B \subset \overline A.$ Thank you for commenting.  ($A$ is open $\iff \forall a\in A, \exists r>0 ; B(a, r)\subset A.$ $A$ is closed $\iff$ $X \setminus A$ is open.)

Comment: We have that $X \setminus \overline A \subseteq X \setminus B$. Indeed, if $x \in X \setminus \overline A$, since the latter set is open we know that there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon) \subseteq X \setminus \overline A$, and so $A \subseteq\overline A \subseteq X \setminus B(x,\varepsilon)$; in other words, we found an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $a \in A$ one has that $\|x-a\| \geq \varepsilon$, i.e. $x \in X \setminus B$.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have a lot to do with norms as such but these are general facts in metric spaces $(X,d)$ and, suitably generalised, even for general spaces.

What you call $B$ is the set of "accumulation points" of $A$, i.e. the set of all points $x \in X$ such that every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$. In a metric space this means that every metric ball $B_d(x,\varepsilon)$ intersects $A$ (for all $\varepsilon>0$) because the topology is generated by the open balls in a metric space. And for a norm this comes down to your definition, as a norm induces a metric by $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ in the standard way.

What you call $C$ is the so-called *sequential closure* of $A$ in general spaces: the set of all limits of sequences from $A$. This is not precisely the closure in general spaces $X$, but we can introduce a more general notion of convergence (called nets, or filters) such that *their* limits will be the closure. For spaces with a countable local base at every point, like metric spaces, and ,by extension, normed spaces we *do* get that sequential closure equals closure (as in the original definition of the intersection of all closed supersets of $A$, i.e. the smallest closed set surrounding $A$).

All this I leant already in my first year of maths schooling in university (in a course called "metric topology", within a few weeks we covered this). It should IMO be part of the text for any serious topology course and not some exercise for the students.

I'm *not* going to do all the proofs of this, because for many parts of this proofs *can* already be found on this site.

See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2245145/4280), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2213744/4280),[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2390678/4280), etc.

Search and ye shall find...

Comment: Others are free to add new links for e.g. sequential closure.